# Add value to serialized object in Sortable

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

```
$(".questions_sortable").sortable({ 
  update: function() {
    var newOrder = $(this).sortable('serialize');
    var toAdd    = {myKey: "A good day"}
    $.post($(this).data('update-url'), newOrder);
  }
});
```

How would I add the variable `toAdd` to the serialized object assigned to the `newOrder` variable, such that both are sent together by the `post` request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.param()` to serialize your object

```
$(".questions_sortable").sortable({ 
  update: function() {
    var newOrder = $(this).sortable('serialize');
     newOrder  +=   '&'+ $.param({myKey: "A good day"});
    $.post($(this).data('update-url'), newOrder);
  }
});
```

**[jQuery.param() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just assign it to the object:

```
newOrder["myKey"] = "A good day";
```

Comment: `newOrder` is a string